# `wget -i files.txt` gives Scheme Missing error on VPS

Tags: bash, wget

I have gathered few min.map files and stored it in `mapfiles.txt`
as shown below,

```
https://example.com/app.bundle.min.map
https://example.com/app.bundle.min.map
https://example.com/app.bundle.min.map
```

I read the `man wget` page and found that to download files using `wget` we need to use
`wget -i filename.txt`

So I tried same thing and observed weird behavior

1. On local system,

`wget -i mapfiles.txt`
This command started downloading .map files

2. On VPS,

`wget -i mapfiles.txt`

Got this error
`https://example/app.bundle.min.map: Scheme missing No URLs found in mapfiles.txt.`

Could you guys help me to figure out where I am going wrong?

Comment: What wget _version_ do you have on that "VPS"? [busybox wget](https://boxmatrix.info/wiki/Property:wget) is not [GNU wget](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wget.1.html).

Comment: On VPS its `GNU Wget 1.19.4 built on linux-gnu` and On local system its `GNU Wget 1.20.3 built on linux-gnu`

Comment: Did you put a Unicode BOM at the start of the file? Does the file have DOS line endings?

Comment: Not sure what unicode BOM or DOS line endings are but on both the systems(local and on VPS) files are in same format as shown above.